# How to get Any user's email Id from facebook graph api

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api

I am using facebook graph api and I am able to get the email id of logged in user. I want to know that how can I retrieve any of my Friends email id using his/her id .

Is it possible or not ?

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is possible to get the data of the user if user has given the permission to access his/her email ID

Comment: Here is the Complete Source Code: https://github.com/lucascorrea/SCFacebook Using this code you can retrieve list of your Friends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot retrieve emails nor phones of your friends through API. Facebook restricts this for security reasons.